# Svn log - svn: '.' is not a working copy

Tags: svn, repository, logging, working-copy

I'm getting "svn: '.' is not a working copy" when i use the svn log command.

I know that i need a working copy for the log command to work but can this be done directly on a repository?

My goal is to display the information (change history) of a repository. I think updating the working copy whenever i need the log information is not a good solution.

Is there an alternative solution to this or updating a working copy every time i need to log is the only way to go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `svn log [repository_url]`

That will get the log of a particular repository rather than the local, checked-out repository.

See [this documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html).

Comment: Like a boss you got it right. I was using the local path to the repository not going through the svnserve. 

That was what i was looking for! Thanks boss.

Answer (score 6):

Use `svnlook log <repos_path>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to supply the full URL, but you DO have a working copy handy, you can also specify that you want the HEAD revision in the repository:

```
svn log -r HEAD:1
```

The default when you omit the -r is as if you had specified `BASE:1` which will only give you changes up to the latest revision pulled down into the working copy.