# What's the right way to overwrite a directory in my SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I have made this mistake several times, and found myself referencing [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729556/svn-log-svn-is-not-a-working-copy) every time I do it.

I have an SVN repository with Assembla, and a local copy checked out on my machine.  When I manually overwrite directories via my OS (i.e. drag and drop a directory over the old one), and then try to SVN ADD and SVN COMMIT I get the ‘.’ is not a working copy error.

Reading the linked post, I understand the error (I think), but what is the right way to do this so I don't have to untangle this error every time?  I'm not using an SVN GUI like Tortoise SVN, just the OSX terminal, if that makes a difference.  Is there a command that I can use?  Feel free to just point me to the documentation, but I googled for it and couldn't find anything.  I saw [SVN COPY](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re07.html), but that says it only works within a working copy, and I want to copy something from my OS over a working copy directory.

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you overwriting with files that are generated?  Are you sure you should be versioning those files?

Comment: @Joel I'm not entirely sure, I have a Drupal website, and the directories I am referencing specifically are downloaded modules; I update them periodically as newer versions are released, so I copy over the entire directory of the module with the new version.  I never touch the files or code inside of them.  But they are still part of the website and I want them backed up, as well as to be able to roll them back if things go awry, so I think it still makes sense to version them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read this over and over and I still don't understand.  The SVN ADD and SVN COMMIT commands are the SVN client software.  What do you mean "I'm not using an SVN client, just the OSX terminal"?

What do you mean "What's the right way to overwrite a directory in my SVN repository?" -- are you trying to delete a directory?  If so, do SVN DEL on your working copy and then commit.

Are you trying to add files to your repository?  If so, use drag-n-drop or "cp/mv" commands and put them into your working copy.  Then SVN ADD them then SVN COMMIT.

SVN maintains its working copies by virtue of hidden ".svn" directories which contain configuration information.  If you remove those, then you get "'.' is not a working copy" errors.  You must not delete or modify the .svn directories.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, you are right my terminology was unclear (/incorrect).  I meant I am not using an SVN GUI interface, like tortoise SVN, I am just using the command line.  I am trying to overwrite a whole directory, without overwriting the hidden .svn files and getting the message, so I think you have answered my question:  I use SVN DEL to remove the directory, and then I can drag and drop or CP before using SVN ADD and SVN COMMIT.  Thanks so much for the help, sorry my question was poorly worded!